# Dynamically loading selects using jquery dual list box plugin

Tags: jquery, grails, listbox

I have a Grails project that I'm using the [[jquery dual listbox plugin]](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx) to populate box2 (granted) with options from box1 (available).

My problem is that in the case of a record that already exists (updating), options that have already been selected do not show up in box 2.  All options appear in box 1 as though they have not already been selected.  What can be done to remove the selected options from box1 (available) and have them appear in box2 (granted)?

The jquery dual list plugin is working as far as moving items from box1 to box2 and vice-versa when the Grant/Deny buttons are used.

Javascript in edit.gsp:

```
$(function() {
    $.configureBoxes({
        transferMode: 'move',
        useFilters: false,
        useCounters: false,
        box1View: 'available',
        box2View: 'granted',
        to1: 'toAvail',
        to2: 'toGranted'
    });
});
```

Selects in edit.gsp:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Available<br/>
                <g:select name="available"
                          id="available"
                          from="${availableList}"
                          value="${user?.granted}"
                          optionKey="id"
                          multiple="multiple"
                          style="height:200px;"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="toGranted" type="button" class="button_right">Grant</button>
                <br/>
                <button id="toAvail" type="button" class="button_left">Deny</button>

            </td>
            <td>
                Granted<br/>
                <g:select name='granted'
                          id="granted"
                          from="[]"
                          multiple="multiple"
                          style="height:200px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

To make things slightly more complicated, box 1 (available) may be populated from an onChange event from another select in the edit.gsp:

```
<g:select name="parent" id="parent"
                              from="${Parent.list()}"
                              optionKey="id"
                              noSelection="[null:'']"
                              value="${user?.parent}"
                              onchange="${remoteFunction(
                                    controller: 'user',
                                    action: 'ajaxGetAvailable',
                                    onSuccess: 'updateAvailable(data)',
                                    params: '\'id=\' + this.value')}"
                    />

function updateAvailable(data) {
  var $element = $('#available');
  var $granted = $('#granted');
  $element.empty();
  $granted.empty();
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $element.append($('<option>').val(data[i].id).text(data[i].name))
  });
}
```

The function above uses a JSON object, from the controller:

```
   def ajaxGetAvailable = {
        def parent = Parent.get(params.id)
        render parent?.available as JSON
   }
```

Classes referenced above:

```
class Parent {
   static mapWith = "mongo"

   String entityId
   String name

   static hasMany = [ available: Entity ]
}

class Entity {

  static mapWith = "mongo"

  String entityId
  String name

  static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating both the Available and Granted selects.  Note the use of Groovy on the "from" to remove the Granted options from the Available options.

```
<g:select name="available"
          id="available"
          from="${availableList - user?.granted}"
          value="${user?.granted}"
          optionKey="id"
          multiple="multiple"
          style="height:200px;"
 />

<g:select name='granted'
          id="granted"
          from="${user?.granted}"
          multiple="multiple"
          optionKey="id"
          style="height:200px;" 
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your granted select has this `from="[]"`.  You would need change the `from` so that it contains a collection of the already granted items you've saved to the database (or wherever).

Also, you would need to filter out the granted items from your `availableList` prior to rendering the view (in your controller).